# Все комбинации для получения числа

Tags: алгоритм

Решаю задачу, уперся в то, что нужно найти все варианты для получения любого четного числа из набора четных положительных чисел

```
sum(i) = M, (i = 2, 4, ..., n)
```

Например, для M = 8, существуют такие наборы

```
2 2 2 2
2 2 4
2 6
4 4 
8
```

Может есть какая-то формула?

Comment: Формула чего? Вам надо наборы найти или просто их количество?

Comment: @tym32167 наборы.

Comment: См. Кнута, том 4А "Искусства программирования".

Comment: @Harry хороший совет, но слишком расплывчат, чтобы быть полезным. Почти как "почитайте книги".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего рекурсивно сделать. Подразумевается, что числа чётные, и это проверять не надо.

```
ПРОЦЕДУРА РАЗЛОЖЕНИЕ(Сумма, Текущий, Набор)
   ЕСЛИ Сумма == 0
        ВЫВОДИТЬ Набор
   ИНАЧЕ
       ДЛЯ X от Текуший до Сумма С_ШАГОМ 2
           РАЗЛОЖЕНИЕ(Сумма- X, X, Набор + [X])
```